# how many hidden layers are required in neural network if i have 1600 input in input layer?

Tags: neural-network

I am working on image processing project. In which, I have to recognize a text from image. So I have segmented the image in letters image. So, I have image of 40*40. So, I am giving a input of 1600 pixels. So can anyone suggest me, how many hidden layers are required? And also suggest, how many neurons are required in hidden layer?

Answer (score 0):

It depends. Are you going to use a convolutional network or a regular fully connected network?

But for either - you have to really find this through trial and error. We have no idea about the complexity of your images, and the size of the text.

What have you tried? 1600 inputs is not *too* much so you could easily run some testcases (start with óne layer of 60 neurons perhaps).

Answer (score -1):

As @Thomas W said, it depends. But there are some experiences you could refer to.

1. [How many hidden layers should I use?](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/ai-faq/neural-nets/part3/section-9.html)
2. [How many hidden units should I use?](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/ai-faq/neural-nets/part3/section-10.html)